# Is it possible to synchronize the Windows's SAM Password to local file

Tags: windows, winapi, credential-providers

I am working on the windows credential provider

We start our project based on this https://github.com/DavidWeiss2/windows-Credential-Provider-library

We want to make this authentication passwordless. Therefore we have a "database" in forms of external file that keep the `password`, `username` and `domain` pairs. Due to security reason we hashed it. (eg: C:\Temp\MyCredsDatabase.dat)

If the user change the password from window's Built-in GUI `System -> Account -> Sign-in Option -> Change Password`, the next login will be failed simply because the user already update their password but our database still using the old password

Well, if I decrypt the password directly from the Microsoft's SAM database it will be whether illegal or hard because Windows keep updating their security package to secure this database.

Is there any possibility that whenever user update the password, we get the password value, and update our "database"?

Or should I save our local database's content with another format?

Like, instead of using the user's information in a plain text for login using our Custom Credential Provider, can I use part of the SAM's value to login?

Comment: It's better to use custom credentials such as smartcard,pin instead of password or SAM which is managed by Microsoft.

Comment: Pin, as in windows hello's pin? For the smartcard, Thank you for your feedback. But we don't want to make this complicated for user by giving user a smartcard. CMIIW

Answer (score 0):

Your credential provider should implement the **CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD** scenario which is triggered in the change password GUI workflow.

At that point, in **ICredentialProviderCredential::GetSerialization**, you should have the raw non encrypted password value.
Then in **ICredentialProviderCredential::ReportResul**t, if *NTSTATUS == STATUS_SUCCESS* you could do whatever you want, including updating your database.

Comment: Thanks for a smart workaround. However, we don't want to change the password through `CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. Instead we want to make our credential provider follows the existing password which is stored inside Microsoft SAM database

Comment: Well that's the only way I can think of to detect a password change.
I guess you could also just use a CPUS_LOGON and detect a failure with STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE which could means a bad password (but also could mean something else and that's a problem), and in that case display a password field you could use to update your database.
I would still advise to use CPUS_CHANGE_PASSWORD though, it's cleaner.

Comment: Well, that's exactly what we are doing right now. `CPUS_LOGON` detect a failure, the password field will be shown. Then, by using that password value, It will update our custom database.